# Select one member from JSON result based on member value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, flickr

I'm working on code which uses the Flickr API and a typical request returns a JSON result like this:

```
{ "sizes": { "canblog": 0, "canprint": 0, "candownload": 1, 
    "size": [
        { "label": "Square", "width": 75, "height": 75, "source": "http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2811\/9227026248_53e958a083_s.jpg", "url": "http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/l0rdshrek\/9227026248\/sizes\/sq\/", "media": "photo" },
        { "label": "Large Square", "width": "150", "height": "150", "source": "http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2811\/9227026248_53e958a083_q.jpg", "url": "http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/l0rdshrek\/9227026248\/sizes\/q\/", "media": "photo" },
        { "label": "Thumbnail", "width": 100, "height": 75, "source": "http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2811\/9227026248_53e958a083_t.jpg", "url": "http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/l0rdshrek\/9227026248\/sizes\/t\/", "media": "photo" },
        { "label": "Small", "width": "240", "height": "180", "source": "http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2811\/9227026248_53e958a083_m.jpg", "url": "http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/l0rdshrek\/9227026248\/sizes\/s\/", "media": "photo" },
        { "label": "Small 320", "width": "320", "height": "240", "source": "http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2811\/9227026248_53e958a083_n.jpg", "url": "http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/l0rdshrek\/9227026248\/sizes\/n\/", "media": "photo" },
        { "label": "Medium", "width": "500", "height": "375", "source": "http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2811\/9227026248_53e958a083.jpg", "url": "http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/l0rdshrek\/9227026248\/sizes\/m\/", "media": "photo" },
        { "label": "Medium 640", "width": "640", "height": "480", "source": "http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2811\/9227026248_53e958a083_z.jpg", "url": "http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/l0rdshrek\/9227026248\/sizes\/z\/", "media": "photo" },
        { "label": "Large", "width": "700", "height": "525", "source": "http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2811\/9227026248_53e958a083_b.jpg", "url": "http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/l0rdshrek\/9227026248\/sizes\/l\/", "media": "photo" },
        { "label": "Original", "width": "700", "height": "525", "source": "http:\/\/farm3.staticflickr.com\/2811\/9227026248_44fe99eea1_o.jpg", "url": "http:\/\/www.flickr.com\/photos\/l0rdshrek\/9227026248\/sizes\/o\/", "media": "photo" }
    ] }, "stat": "ok" }
```

What I'd like to do is, using JavaScript and jQuery, check whether the result contains a `size` member which has a `label` value of "Large" (for instance), and then extract just that member of the result so I can read from its `source` and `url` values.

I naively tried the following:

```
var photoURL, thumbURL, photoLink;
$.ajax({ //inner request to Flickr for photo sizes
    type: 'GET',  
    url: getSizeUrl,  
    dataType: 'json', 
    async: true,  
    success: function(sizeData){
        var sizeResults = sizeData.sizes.size;

        if(sizeResults[label="Large"]) {
            photoURL = sizeResults[label="Large"].source;
        }
}});
```

But the `sizeResults[label="Large"]` syntax is seemingly invalid. I've hunted around for over an hour trying to find the correct way to do this, but I must be using the wrong search terms because I can't find any examples of this sort of data extraction. Can it be done? [If this has already been well covered by another Stack Overflow question, please point me to it and I'll delete this duplicate.]

If it's not possible to do things this way, what is an efficient way to check for and examine the "Large" record from the above JSON result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `$.grep` for this. It's clean and simple to use.

```
var a = $.grep(data.sizes.size, function (size) { 
  // here you'll get an object of data. You'll have to use the filter condition here   
  return size["label"] === "Large";
})[0]; // you'll get an [{}] if you don't use [0] in the end. 
// now, you'll get just {} because of the [0] in the end.
```

From here on, you could just say,

```
var photoURL = a.source;
```

This will return every element in `data.sizes.size` that has a label called "Large" in it. [See  more in docs here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/).

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vLaUB/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could put them all into an array of objects, and then have some sort of key on the objects, or you could just loop through the results:

```
$.each(sizeResults, function(index, value) { 
  if (value.label == "Large") {
    photoURL = value.source;
    return false; // breaks out of the loop.
  }
});
```

Certainly not efficient, but it should be fast enough...

Answer (score 0):

Using pure JavaScript:

```javascript
var large = sizeResults.filter(function(x) { return x.label === 'Large'; })[0];
large; // =>  { "label": "Large", "width": "700", "height": "525" ... }
```